# ElasticSearch to get minimum_should_match along with order

Tags: database, elasticsearch, query-string, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to get the elastic output for "every dog has a good day", where in i want elastic to return even if we have a partial match (*minimum_should_match* = 4) and also maintain a continuous(sequential) order. So far i have tried below query, but this doesn't maintain the order. Is there any way where in i can specify the order along with *minimum_should_match*.

> Query : "Every dog has a day"

```
"query": 
{
    "match" : {
        "extracted_raw_text" : {
            "query" : "every dog has a good day",
            "minimum_should_match": 4,
        }
    }   
}
```

Expected Output :

> "somewords here and there every dog good day. New sentence" (Want this output even
> when 2 words are missed from the query order maintained)

Answer (score 0):

you could use `match_phrase_prefix` with a slop of 2 or 3

```json
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "message": {
        "query": "every dog has a good day",
        "slop": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

you could also specify an analyzer to remove the stopwords like `has` and `a`

more documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html